# Azure Active Directory (AAD) Authentication Plug-in for SonarQube : ERROR

Tags: sonarqube, azure-active-directory, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-ops

I installed and config Azure Active Directory (AAD) Authentication Plug-in for SonarQube (version 1.1) by using [this](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-aad) guide.

When i click on the "Loginn with Azure AD", i have this error :

[image]

This is the url in the browser after clicked on this button :

```
h t t p s://my_url_sonar/id_of_my_azure_ad/oauth2/authorize?client_id=myclientid&response_type=code&redirect_uri= h t t p s://my_url_sonar/oauth2/callback/aad&state=1b1juq17lb8nlka7mjvirlq03t
```

Comment: Is it on purpose to have "id_of_my_azure_ad" in the URL ? Did you configure it as a web context ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Comment: HI Simon, i don't know. This url is gerenated automaticaly. I juste config extactely the azure ad into sonar like this guide :( : https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-auth-aad